# How to implement a form reset button in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I use a reset button to delete form input? I want to delete these  search filters to clear an ASP.NET Core search filter

I use a JS function to clear these inputs, but it doesn't work.

**Index page:**

```
<form  id="form">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.TextBox("nom", null, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Par nom",id="nom" })


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.TextBox("prenom", null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Par prenom" ,id="prenom"})


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.TextBox("email", null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Par email" ,id="email"})


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.TextBox("telephone", null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Par telephone" ,id="telephone"})


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">

            <p>


                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />

                <button class="btn" type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetFields()" asp-action="Clear" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>

            </p>

        </div>



    </div>
</form>


> Blockquote
```

**action Index:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string nom, string prenom, string email, string telephone, int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
    {
        
        if (nom != null || prenom != null || email != null || telephone != null)
        {
            pageNumber = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            nom = currentFilter;
            prenom = currentFilter;
            email = currentFilter;
            telephone = currentFilter;
        }

        var personnels = from s in _context.personnels
                         select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nom) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(prenom) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(telephone))
        {
            personnels = personnels.Where(s => s.Nom.Equals(nom) || s.Prenom.Equals(prenom) || s.Email.Equals(email) || s.Telephone.Equals(telephone));
        }
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nom) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(prenom) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(telephone))
        {
            personnels = personnels.Where(s => s.Nom.Equals(nom) && s.Prenom.Equals(prenom) && s.Email.Equals(email) && s.Telephone.Equals(telephone));
        }
            int pageSize = 20;
        return View(await Pagination<PersonnelModel>.CreateAsync(personnels.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));


    }
```

**code javascript**

```
function Reset() {
   
    document.getElementById('nom').value = '';
    document.getElementById('prenom').value = '';
    document.getElementById('email').value = '';
    document.getElementById('telephone').value = '';

    

    }
```

Comment: Your button calls `resetFields()` but your function is `Reset()`

Comment: In your code your are just setting control values to empty strings. You need to also submit the form so that search action will be called with empty search parameters and it will return all the data. `document.forms["form"].submit()`

Comment: it is just a copy fault sorry,in my code i wrote Reset (),i want to clear filter and clear inputs  after search,but how to use this document.forms["form"].submit() please,I also try to make another code but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

it is just a copy fault sorry,in my code i wrote Reset (),i want to clear filter and clear inputs after search,but how to use this document.forms["form"].submit() please,I also try to make another code but it doesn't work,Thank you very much in advance for any kind of help.

**Index action:**

```
public string searchNom { get; set; }
        public string searchPrenom { get; set; }
        public string searchEmail { get; set; }
        public string searchTelephone { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchNom, string searchPrenom, string searchEmail, string searchTelephone, int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
        {
            
            if (searchNom != null || searchPrenom != null || searchEmail != null || searchTelephone != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;

            }
            

            var personnels = from s in _context.personnels
                             select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNom) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPrenom) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchEmail) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTelephone))
            {
                personnels = personnels.Where(s => s.Nom.Equals(searchNom) || s.Prenom.Equals(searchPrenom) || s.Email.Equals(searchEmail) || s.Telephone.Equals(searchTelephone));
                ViewData["sNom"] = searchNom ;
                ViewData["sPrenom"] = searchPrenom;
                ViewData["sEmail"] = searchEmail;
                ViewData["sTelephone"] =searchTelephone ;
                
            }

            else
            {
                ViewData["sNom"] = "";
                ViewData["sPrenom"] = "";
                ViewData["sEmail"] = "";
                ViewData["sTelephone"] = "";
            }
          
            
                int pageSize = 20;
            return View(await Pagination<PersonnelModel>.CreateAsync(personnels.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
```

**my index.cshtml**

```
<form  method="post"id="form">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchNom" value="@ViewData["sNom"]?.ToString()" class="form-control" id="nom" />


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchPrenom" value="@ViewData["sPrenom"]?.ToString()"  id="prenom"/>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchEmail" value="@ViewData["sEmail"]?.ToString()" id="email"/>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchTelephone" value="@ViewData["sTelephone"]?.ToString()" id="telephone"/>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">

            <p>


                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />

                <button class="btn" type="reset" id="reset" onclick="Reset()"  ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>

            </p>

        </div>



    </div>
</form>


        }
```

**code.js**

```
function Reset() {
   
    
   
    
  
    document.querySelector('input[name=searchNom]').value = null;
    document.querySelector('input[name=searchPrenom]').value = null;
    document.querySelector('input[name=searchEmail]').value = null;
    document.querySelector('input[name=searchTelephone]').value = null;
    }
```

the reset button doesn't work,there is an exception :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of null
at Reset ((index):350)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):107)